# Netezza insert into error

Tags: sql, temp-tables, netezza, insert-into

Working in Netezza and trying to run the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE COUNTS
AS SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROWCOUNT, 'CA' AS PLAN FROM TABLE1;

INSERT INTO COUNTS
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2, 'FL');

SELECT * FROM COUNTS;
```

But for some reason, it doesn't like the 'FL' part and if I remove it:

```
INSERT INTO COUNTS
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2);
```

it runs fine but with a NULL where I wanted FL to be.

I don't know what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be  you must declare the column explicitally

```
 INSERT INTO COUNTS(ROWCOUNT, PLAN)
 SELECT COUNT(*), 'FL' FROM TABLE2';
```

Comment: what mean " Doesn't work "  .. have you error ?   . worng result?  no result?

Comment: Anyway  .. i have update the asnwer for the second column